# Cauchy sequence which does not converge example.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the normed space $(X, \Vert \cdot\Vert) $ where
$$
X=\{  (a_n)_n \quad|\quad (a_n)_n \text{ real sequence with } \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0   \}
$$
and 
$$\Vert (a_n)_n\Vert:= \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|a_n|}{2^n} .$$
I am looking for a Cauchy sequence in $(X, \Vert \cdot\Vert)$ which does not converge.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? For example, have you tried looking at a family of sequences which have some constant nonzero value for longer and longer periods of time and then drop to $0$?

Comment: @MihaHabič I will try to follow your hint. Thanks.

Comment: @MihaHabič I tried but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

For each $m$ define a sequence $(a^m_n)_n$ by
$$a^m_n=\begin{cases}1;&n\leq m\\ 0;&n>m\end{cases}$$
Clearly each $(a^m_n)_n$ is in $X$. Furthermore, if $m\geq m'$ then
$$\|(a^m_n)_n-(a^{m'}_n)_n\|=\sum_{k=m'+1}^m\frac{1}{2^k}\leq \frac{1}{2^{m'}}$$
which shows that the sequence of the $(a^m_n)_n$ is Cauchy. But this sequence cannot converge. Any potential limit $(b_n)_n$ in $X$ has to have $\lim_n b_n=0$,
so in particular $b_n\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$ for some large enough $N$. But then
$$\|(b_n)_n-(a^m_n)_n\|\geq \frac{m-N+1}{2}$$ for any $m\geq N$, showing that the $(a^m_n)_n$ do not converge to $(b_n)_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_n$
has
$1$ $1$,
$2$ $1/2$,
$4$ $1/4$,
...
$2^n$ $1/2^n$.

Then
$a_n \to 0$,
but,
like the proof that
the harmonic sum diverges,
you can show that
$\sum\frac{a_n}{2^n}$
diverges.